# Javascript loop works the first time ran, but gives NaN the second time without logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm developing a javascript game and am altering values from a JSON file through a loop. The loop however occasionally replaces the values it should alter with "NaN" and grabs a random letter from the prefix word of the array. I tried debugging the values and putting in fixed creature values, but that has made me none the wiser.

The code works THE FIRST TIME RAN in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezwad5mL/2/ but whenever you run it a second time, it overwrites the values in the loop with NaN and the letter. I think it's because the function `random_int` needs 2 values but it only inputs 1 the second time you run it, which is somehow the same value from the previous input (which it altered in the second For loop). What I don't understand is how this code doesn't reset the `storedDungeon` if it fires the second time.

I understand the problem I think, but I have no clue what's wrong with what I wrote and why it does okay the first time, but screws up the second time.

```
function random_item(items){
  return items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
}

function random_int(min, max) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var storedDungeon = []

const jsonCreatures = {
   "easy":  [
     { "name": "Scorchbird", "hp": [6,13], "prefix": ["Weak", "Small", "Young", "Wild"], 
       "damage": [1,5], "droprateCommon": [0,60], "droprateRare": [70, 90]},
     { "name": "Reanimated Corpse", "hp": [8,15], "prefix": ["Weak", "Festering"], "damage": 
       [3,5], "droprateCommon": [0,40], "droprateRare": [50, 80]}
]}

var randNumber = 2

for (let i = 0; i < randNumber; i++) {
  let randomObject = random_item(jsonCreatures.easy)
  storedDungeon.push(randomObject)
}

for (let o = 0; o < storedDungeon.length; o++) {
  storedDungeon[o].hp = random_int(storedDungeon[o].hp[0], storedDungeon[o].hp[1])
  storedDungeon[o].damage = random_int(storedDungeon[o].damage[0],storedDungeon[o].damage[1])
  storedDungeon[o].prefix = random_item(storedDungeon[o].prefix)
 }

console.log(storedDungeon)
```

Comment: First, be aware your mutating your jsonCreatures,  and second, when you do mutate your not replacing   hp,damage & prefix with another array, you forgot to place them inside `[]`..

Comment: I see it, but I don't understand how I'm mutating the jsonCreatures. It just gets a random object out of it, it does not alter right?

Comment: In Javascript when you assign an object as in -> `let randomObject = random_item(jsonCreatures.easy)`  your not actually making a copy, your making a reference to the same object.  Even after pushing that object to another array -> `storedDungeon.push(randomObject)`  `randomeObject` will still be only a reference, and when you do -> `storedDungeon[o].hp = ....` your assigning to the referenced object.  In a nutshell Javascript passes object by reference, and thats why your mutating..

Comment: Thank you guys for explaining it to me! I'm just scratching the surface of programming and had no idea that objects were references. I think I learned something new and valuable today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the problem we need to understand how arrays work.
The following example may open your eyes to the problem.

```
const creatures = [
  {
    name: 'Scorchbird'
  }
]

const dungeon = []
dungeon.push(creatures[0])
dungeon[0].name = 'Reference to the object!'

console.log(creatures)
// [
//   {
//     name: 'Reference to the object!'
//   }
// ]
```

When we add a creature (object) to our dungeon array

```
dungeon.push(creatures[0])
```

we actually add a reference to the original object, not a copy of it.

This means that when you do

```
storedDungeon[o].hp = random_int(
    storedDungeon[o].hp[0],
    storedDungeon[o].hp[1]
  )
```

you alter the original creatures objects and their properties.

In this case the array `hp: [6, 13]` is replaced with a random (single!) number, for example `hp: 8`
And when your code runs the second time there is now hp array to do `hp[0]` and `hp[1]`, just a single number. This is why the function `random_int` returns NaN (not a number).

The same effect happens with the damage and with the prefix. However because prefix is a string the `random_item` function will return a random character in this string. That's because the characters of a string can be accessed by their index like in an array: `"im a string"[1] = "m"`

Answer (score 1):

I think Nico Gräf's explanation is correct. To fix this, you can create a clone of the object and have it pushed to the `storedDungeon`.

```
storedDungeon.push({...randomObject})
```

Please note that `spread syntax` doesn't **deep clone** your object. So it only works to the first level of the object, which should be fine with your current design.